# Как правильно настроить gitignore в android проекте?

Tags: android, git, gitignore

Как правильно настроить файл gitignore для android проекта, чтобы работать с ним в Git?

На скрине я выделил то, о чём точно знаю, что надо добавить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно если выбрать в отображении проекта пункт **Android**, то там можно добавить сразу все?

[image: отображение проекта "Android"]

Comment: В дополнение еще можно просто сервисом воспользоваться – https://www.gitignore.io/api/android

Comment: Не увидел, что я продублировал вопрос. Удалить не получается, так как есть ответы. Что обычно делают в таких случаях? Я недавно Stack Overflow пользуюсь, еще не освоился на 100%))

Comment: Можете ничего не делать, данный вопрос уже помечен как дубликат. Если у вас будут еще подобный вопросы про сообщество, можно смотреть на Мете – http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Можно [отсюда](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) взять:

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/
```